# Is there any way to get rid of the gray area in iCal?

Tags: macos, ical

The gray area I'm referring to is the area that's not used, say from 12am to 6am.

I want to get rid of this area entirely (It's not the color that's the issue). I don't use that space at all, so it means I have to scroll down to schedule something every single time -- seems very counter-intuitive imho.

**Edit:** Simplified to one question.

**Edit:** Still no solution, but some workarounds are provided below. An actual solution would be best though. (Not to take anything away from those who contributed).

Comment: Generally you get better results if you don't combine several questions into one. Feel free to create a new question for #2 (as #1 got an answer below) and edit this question here accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer 1. Go to preferences in iCal, and set "day starts at" to midnight, and "day ends at" to midnight. Or... whenever you want the grey area not to go. So 8-6 (default I think) will make 8-6 not grey. Here's a screen scrape of how that looks:

[image]

Comment: what I wanted was say 7am to midnight, and that other time (from 12am to 7am) to be cut out, i.e. not be displayed at all because that time is useless to me. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK, that was unclear from the question. You may want to edit the question so it's clear that you want to get rid of those hours, and not the grey coloring.

Answer (score 0):

Follow @lemontwist's directions to set the day start and end times to just the hours that you want to see. Then change the "Show [X] hours at a time" to that number of hours. You'll have to scroll the view into place once, but then it seems like it sticks there.

For example, if you set the day to start at 8:00 and end at 6:00, then set it to show 10 hours at a time and scroll the view down to 8:00. The visible area will then cover 8:00 to 6:00 and you shouldn't have to adjust it again.

Comment: Yeah, I can still scroll to it though. Especially since I use my mouse wheel tilt to move through the calendar (in week view), it makes it more likely I'll scroll back to the gray area. Thanks though

Comment: I still haven't found a solution, but so far yours is a decent work around.