# Disable scrolling in iCal and iTunes when apps aren't selected

Tags: itunes, ical

Sometimes I'll have iCal or iTunes open alongside another app, and I'll accidentally scroll up or down while the mouse is hovering over iCal or iTunes and it will actually scroll even though neither of the apps are selected.

How do I disable scrolling on iCal and iTunes when the app isn't selected?

Note: I'm on a 2011 MBP w/ Lion

Comment: Many people love this single feature about OS X and you want to disable it?

Comment: @duci9y See answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75628/is-there-any-way-to-get-rid-of-the-gray-area-in-ical